# Assign values to variable using loop VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have variables declared in VBA function like A1,A2,A3.....An

and assigned values to A1,A2,A3...An

now how can I update values in the variables using loop

```
Dim A1, A2, A3 As Integer, Tmp As String
A1 = 1
A2 = 2
A3 = 3


For i = 1 To 3

    Debug.Print A & i
    A & i  = i+1 --- This line is not working
Next
```

How can I assign variables without using any arrays

Comment: In short you can't.  That is what Arrays are for.

Comment: You cannot construct a variable out of two parts like that, you need an Array, see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm

Comment: If you need named identifiers, use a `Scripting.Dictionary` instead.

Comment: Note:  Your `Dim` statement is declaring `A1` and `A2` as `Variant`.  If you expected to declare them as `Integer` you need to use `Dim A1 As Integer, A2 As Integer, A3 As Integer, Tmp As String`

Comment: Why "without using arrays"? Because you don't understand them? That's *exactly* what they exist for. Learn to use them, learn to love them. They'll love you in return and together you'll write awesome code. Don't give up!

Answer (score 2):

Re-consider using arrays:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim A(1 To 3) As Long
    A(1) = 1
    A(2) = 2
    A(3) = 3
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a collection to do this, and later loop the collection or get the value by passing in the key (variable name)

```
Sub TestCollection()
Dim i As Long
Dim objCollection As New Collection
Dim varVariable As Variant

    'Loop From 1 To 3. The Upper Bound Can Be Changed To Suit Your Needs
    For i = 1 To 3
        'Add The Key And Item To The Collection
        'The First Parameter Is The Item (Value You Want To Store)
        'The Second Parameter Is The Key (How You Access The Value, Like A Variable Name)
        objCollection.Add i, "A" & i
    Next i

    'The Value Passed Into The Collection Is The Key - Which Is Like The Variable Name
    Debug.Print objCollection("A1")
    Debug.Print objCollection("A2")
    Debug.Print objCollection("A3")

    'Loop All Values
    For Each varVariable In objCollection
        Debug.Print varVariable
    Next varVariable

End Sub
```